# How to perform cross navigation with SpagoBI

Tags: spagobi

i've selected a column name of a table and have created the hyperlink using javascript:
"javascript:parent.execCrossNavigation(this.name.'child_report','pclass'="+row("class")+");" ,
where 'child_report' is chid document which must appear when hyperlink in master report is clicked, pclass is some parameter, class is the column name in master report document.  But, when i run this master report in spagoBI, it's not showing hyperlink. Can anyone give me the suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This should be the format should be as shown

> Ensure you have the hyperlink type as "URI"
>   "javascript:parent.execCrossNavigation(this.name,'child_report','pclass="+row["class"]+");"

Happy reporting ;)